BScScan "File Import Callback not supported" for openzepplin
I am trynig to get my token verified on BscScan and here is the code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Context.sol";


contract XXXX is ERC20, Ownable {
uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 1_800_000_000 * 10**7; // 1.8 billion tokens with 7 decimals
uint256 public tokenPrice = 625; // Price of XXX token in USDC (0.00625 USD)

// Constructor to mint initial supply to the contract owner
constructor() ERC20("XXXX", "xxx") Ownable(msg.sender) {
    _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
}

// Mint new tokens 
function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
    _mint(to, amount);
}

// Burn tokens from the caller's wallet
function burn(uint256 amount) external {
    _burn(msg.sender, amount);
}

// Allow the owner to burn tokens from any account
function burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
    _spendAllowance(account, msg.sender, amount);
    _burn(account, amount);
}

// Function to change the token price in USDC terms
function setTokenPrice(uint256 newPrice) external onlyOwner {
    tokenPrice = newPrice;
}

// Function to swap USDC for xxx tokens
function buyTokens(address usdcToken, uint256 usdcAmount) external {
    require(usdcAmount > 0, "Send a valid amount of USDC");

    // Transfer USDC from investor to the owner's wallet
    require(
        IERC20(usdcToken).transferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), usdcAmount),
        "USDC transfer failed"
    );

    uint256 tokensToTransfer = (usdcAmount * 10**7) / tokenPrice;
    require(balanceOf(owner()) >= tokensToTransfer, "Not enough tokens available");

    // Transfer tokens to investor
    _transfer(owner(), msg.sender, tokensToTransfer);
}
}

I also tried downloading the files from github and calling it locally but I still get the same error. How can I fix this?
Thank you

Could you elaborate which framework you are using to verify your contract? Is it Hardhat, Truffle, or Foundry? So that I can tell you solution accordingly.

Foundry doesn't support this. Read more here.
I recommend you to install the OpenZeppelin library using:
forge install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
And then import the contracts:
import {ERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {Context} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";

